# setTimeout and animation inside an earlier function

Tags: jquery, function, settimeout

To get rid of animation buildup caused by `setTimeout` (or `setInterval` either) during tab(window) inactivity (loose of focus) I had to use the *recursive callback* like:

```
function auto() {
interval = setTimeout(function() {      
    $('#slider').animate({left: '-=500'}, 800, function(){
          auto();         // THE RECURSIVE CALLBACK
    });
}, 2000);
}
auto();
```

Now I'd like **NOT** to reuse the `#slider`'s **animation** itself cause I've already defined it in an earlier `function animate()` (without changing the `function animate` cause I have to use it in other places like-it-is):

```
function animate(){
    $('#slider').animate({left: '-=500'}, 800);
}
```

**How to get work something like this** :

```
function auto() {
interval = setTimeout(function() {  

      animation();auto();  // THIS IS WRONG AS NOT a RECURSIVE CALLBACK - and creates animation buildup     

}, 2000);
}
auto();
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `animate` accept a calback:

```
function animate(cb){
    $('#slider').animate({left: '-=500'}, 800, cb);
}

//...

interval = setTimeout(function() {  
    animation(function(){
        auto();
    });   
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Hi Felix! (+1000!) this is just great, do you have the time to explain how the hell this callback is not interfering (as I expected to see) with other actions to the same animation? ... THANKS!

Comment: @roXon: I guess you mean why it does not cause any problems with other code which calls the function without callback? If no callback is passed, then `cb` will be `undefined` and passing `undefined` to a function is very similar to not passing the argument at all (similar to calling `.animate({left: '-=500'}, 800)` in this case). The only difference is that the internal `argument` object will still show an `undefined` argument, but that should not cause any trouble.

Comment: Great trick Felix! (forgot about 'beeing undefined' ) Thank you very much! ( Wow you gained an impressive score in a short period of time! You rock! )